# PrepareForReuse not resetting properties and cells retaining behaviour after reusing

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcell

In my collectionView cell, I have a label which is inside a UIView. So the cell must resize itself according to width of the label, the height is fixed. Here is how I have set up the code for fixed height & dynamic width, just in case as I have seen some examples where constraints can cause weird behaviour:

```
   cvButtons.delegate = self
   cvButtons.dataSource = self
   cvButtons.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 7, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

and here is the `layoutConfig()` code:

```
 func layoutConfig() -> UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout {
        return UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { (sectionNumber, env) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in
            let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .estimated(44), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1))
            let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
            let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .estimated(44), heightDimension: .absolute(40))
            let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
            let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
            section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .continuous
            return section
        }
    }
```

All this is working fine and cells are created perfectly, like every cell width is dynamic as required. However my requirement is that when the view is loaded, the view in first cell should have blue background. So I wrote this code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if collectionView == cvButtons {
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ButtonCategoriesCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ButtonCategoriesCollectionViewCell
                        
            let data = tableSctionHeader[indexPath.row]
            
            cell.lblCategory.text = data
            
            if indexPath.item == 0 {
                cell.setBlueColor()
            }
            else {
                cell.setDefault()
            }
            
            return cell
}
```

And this is my collectionView cell class:

```
import UIKit

class ButtonCategoriesCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var viewCard: UIView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var lblCategory: UILabel!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        
        setDefault()
    }
    
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        self.setDefault()
    }
    
    func setDefault() {
        viewCard.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        viewCard.layer.borderWidth = 1
        viewCard.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        viewCard.setviewShadowCustomInputs(shadowColor: UIColor.clear.cgColor, shadowOpacity: 0, shadowRadius: 0, shadowWidth: 0, shadowHeight: 0)
    }
    
    func setBlueColor() {
        viewCard.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "Color1")
        viewCard.layer.borderWidth = 0
        viewCard.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        viewCard.setViewShadow()
        lblCategory.textColor = UIColor.white
    }
    
}
```

This code works fine however im reloading the data by using another collectionView. So if I select some item in that collectionView, the data refreshes and above cells should reload with new data which works fine, the number of cells changes and labels too however in some cases instead of index == 0, some other items also retain blue colour. In some cases, all items are showing blue colour instead of the item at the first index. This is the function im using to update above collectionView:

```
func updateCollectionView(index: Int) {
        if index == 1 {
            collectionViewArray = array1
        }
        else if index == 2 {
            collectionViewArray = array2
        }
        else if index == 3 {
            collectionViewArray = array3
        }
        else if index == 4 {
            collectionViewArray = array4
        }
        else if index == 5 {
            collectionViewArray = array5
        }
        else if index == 6 {
            collectionViewArray = array6
        }
        else if index == 7 {
            collectionViewArray = array7
        }
        else {
            collectionViewArray = array8
        }
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
```

And im just calling this function in `didSelectAnItem` of other collectionView and passing indexPath from that.

Is this the proper way to use `prepareForReuse`?

Answer (score 0):

The `prepareForReuse()` method restores the cell to its initial state.

If you make any customizations to the cell's appearance in `cellForItem(at:)`, you generally want to revert these changes back to default state in `prepareForReuse()`.

In the code that you shared, the problem is the following:

1. For a certain index path, you call `cell.setBlueColor()`.
2. The `setBlueColor()` changes `viewCard.backgroundColor`.
3. When the same cell is reused for another index path, UIKit calls the cell's `prepareForReuse()` method which in turn calls the `setDefault()` method.
4. However, the `setDefault()` method never restores `viewCard.backgroundColor` back to its original value.

If you add a line to `setDefault()` that sets `viewCard.backgroundColor` back to its original value that you have set in a storyboard/XIB, it should work. You probably also need to reset `lblCategory.textColor` back to its original value.

However, this code can be improved even further:

1. In `prepareForReuse()`, don't set the properties that you never change in `cellForItem(at:)`. Instead, set them just once in `awakeFromNib()`. For example, you never change the corner radius, so just move that line to `awakeFromNib()`.
2. Since both `awakeFromNib()` and `prepareForReuse` call the `setDefault()` method, you don't need to call it again from `cellForItem(at:)` when you're not doing any visual customization of a cell. That's just a wasted CPU time that doesn't have any effect.